# Oracle analytics SUM SQL does not sum one at a time in window

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

### Problem

Looking at [SUM Analytic Function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sum-analytic-function) in [Oracle Base](https://oracle-base.com/) and running the SQL expecting the SUM would add the salary one row at a time.

```
SELECT 
  deptno,
  ename,
  sal,
  SUM(sal)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY deptno 
      ORDER BY sal 
      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) 
    AS RUNNING_TOTAL_IN_DEPT
FROM
  emp
ORDER BY deptno, sal
;
```

However, for the row with the same salary value, the sub total of the rows with the same salary value is added.

```
DEPTNO  ENAME   SAL     RUNNING_TOTAL_IN_DEPT
20      SMITH   800     800
20      ADAMS   1100    1900
20      JONES   2975    4875
20      SCOTT   3000    10875 <--- Why not 7875? How to make this to 7875?
20      FORD    3000    10875 

30      JAMES   950     950
30      MARTIN  1250    3450 <--- Why not 2200?
30      WARD    1250    3450
30      TURNER  1500    4950
30      ALLEN   1600    6550
```

### Question

Please explain this behaviour and how to add the sum one row at a time even when there are multiple rows with the same salary value.

Comment: Use `rows` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `RANGE BETWEEN` rather than `ROWS BETWEEN`.  `RANGE BETWEEN` treats all rows with the same key values as the same, so they all get the "full" value.

The Oracle documentation doesn't do a great job explaining this.  [Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_windowing_clause.htm) is a blog post that provides some background.

Answer (score 2):

You want `ROWS BETWEEN` instead of `RANGE BETWEEN` :

```
SELECT deptno, ename, sal,
       SUM(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal 
                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RUNNING_TOTAL_IN_DEPT
FROM emp
ORDER BY deptno, sal;
```